# Point class in C#

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to C# and I'm trying to do something but without much success. I am trying to use the class `Point` (the one with coordinates).

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace app2{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){

            Point p1 = new Point();
            p1.X = 7;
            p1.Y = 6;

            Console.WriteLine(p1.X);
            Console.WriteLine(p1.Y);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }     
    }
}
```

The error is :

> The type or namespace Point could not be found

I've been using this class in Java in a very similar manner, am I supposed to declare my own `Point` class/function which returns X and Y coordinates?

Comment: Tip: If you hover over the problematic Word and see a small blue Point, you can open a Context-Menu and get some Actions like the Namespace-Include etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should add a reference to your solution, to the namespace `System.Drawing`.

From the tab 'Solution Explorer', right click on 'References' and select 'Add Reference', as shown below:

[image: SolutionExplorer]

In the new window, type in the search bar '`System.Drawing`'. Double click in the results found and click the button 'OK'.

Now, in your code, where the other `using` statements are declared, add the following line:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Note: I noticed you're creating a new Console application. Be aware that, if you want to create a basic user interface, the `System.Drawing.Point` structure won't help you, because in a Console application you cannot interact with the user using buttons, labels and coordinates useful to place your UI items. In a Console application, you can interact only using plain text.
If you want to create a simple application with a basic user interface, create instead a Windows Forms application.

Comment: Please add System.Windows.Point to your reply too, it is available since .Net 3.0 and is preferred over System.Drawing when used for non display purposes, i.e. calculations in services. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The `Point` class is located at `System.Drawing`, so at the top you should write

```
using System.Drawing
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Point` **structure** is a part of the `System.Drawing` namespace.
You can either reference this namespace or create your own Point structure, which, if you only need it as a coordinate container could be a very simple structure.

Something like:

```
public struct Point 
{
   public int X {get;set;}
   public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

---

Altho, the original `Point` struct in the `System.Drawing` namespace got a few more functions than the above code (which obviously don't have any, hehe). If you need those, I would recommend including the `System.Drawing` namespace instead of making your own, cause it would probably take more time than you wish that it took for such a simple structure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.point.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to use a simple structure for 2 ints, you can use the Tuple class (from the System namespace).

`Tuple<int, int> point = new Tuple<int, int>(2, 5);`

In time: As stated by @Aaron Hudon on comments, be aware that a Tuple is a class (so, by using it you'll be having an instance's reference) while a Point is a struct.
Thanks for the observation Aaron Hudon.

Comment: A `Tuple` is a reference type, whereas `Point` is a value type.  They aren't the same.

Comment: No intention on implying that Tuple and Point are completely similar. Just pointing out that if the OP's need is for something simple that can hold 2 int values, the Tuple instance could be used in a very straightforward manner. But it is in fact important to point out the difference, so I'm including your observation on the suggestion posted. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

Move your cursor to the `Point` in your code and use the swift keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. In there, you can easily attach the necessary namespace - in your case, it will be `System.Drawing`.

With that shortcut you can decide if you want to attach the whole namespace, or just use it localy, like `SystemDrawing.Point _Point = new SystemDrawing.Point();`

Bear in mind that you may have to add the library reference - you use a console program, which doesn't have Windows Forms .dll files (as it would be unwise to attach all the unnecessary libraries). You have to add one manually.

Go to you project in solution explorer, right click on `References`, `add reference`, `Assemblies` and then check the `System.Drawing`. Ounce you add that and the correct namespace (`using System.Drawing`), it will work.

Answer (score 2):

you need add `using System.Drawing` at top.